# Using Css separately at styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, web

I made a code using styled-components.

Used map function for making repeated components and it worked well.

But I want to use 'clr' in the 'cardProperty' array for color. So I need to deliever 'clr' to styled-components. But don't know how to deliver it and which way would be effective.

Question:
*How can I use 'clr' in the 'h2' tag separately using styled-components?*

**code:**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const cardProperty = [
  {
    clr: "#009688",
    name: "Sea",
    img: "img1.jpg",
  },
  {
    clr: "#03a9f4",
    name: "Sky",
    img: "img2.jpg",
  },
  {
    clr: "#ff3e7f",
    name: "Mountain",
    img: "img3.jpg",
  },
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Wrap>
      <div className="container">
        {cardProperty.map((idx) => {
          return (
            <div className="card">
              <div className="imgBx">
                <img src={idx.img} />
              </div>
              <div className="content">
                <h2>{idx.name}</h2>
                <p>
                  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab
                  commodi officia aspernatur error. Veritatis quisquam rem quis
                  ut, necessitatibus aut aperiam adipisci odio voluptatem quos
                  totam esse sit dolorem incidunt?
                </p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </Wrap>
  );
}

const Wrap = styled.div`
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00bcd4, #ffeb3b);

  .container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 100px 50px;
    padding: 100px 50px;
  }

  .container .card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 350px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 35px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .container .card:hover {
    height: 400px;
  }

  .container .card .imgBx {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 220px;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .container .card:hover .imgBx {
    top: -100px;
    scale: 0.75;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 45px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }

  .container .card .imgBx img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  .container .card .content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 252px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .container .card:hover .content {
    top: 130px;
    height: 250px;
  }

  .container .card .content h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: // want to use it here
  }
`;
```

**CodeSandBox**
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-darwin-y0pvi1?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you can try passing color props to `styled-component`.
Something like this:

```
const Typography = styled.h2`
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: ${(props) => props.color}; // dynamic color prop
`;

Typography.defaultProps = {
  color: "#000000"; // default color if nothing is passed
};


const cardProperty = [
  {
    clr: "#009688",
    name: "Sea",
    img: "img1.jpg",
  },
  {
    clr: "#03a9f4",
    name: "Sky",
    img: "img2.jpg",
  },
  {
    clr: "#ff3e7f",
    name: "Mountain",
    img: "img3.jpg",
  },
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
        {cardProperty.map((idx) => {
          return (
            <div className="card">
              <div className="imgBx">
                <img src={idx.img} />
              </div>
              <div className="content">
                <Typography color={idx.clr}>{idx.name}</Typography>

                <p>
                  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab commodi officia aspernatur error.
                  Veritatis quisquam rem quis ut, necessitatibus aut aperiam adipisci odio voluptatem quos totam esse
                  sit dolorem incidunt?
                </p>
                <a href="#">Read More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </>
  );
}
```

Also if you wish to use this component as global dynamic typography you can do this:

```
// typography.js
const Typography = styled(props => <props.tag {...props}>{props.children}</props.tag>)`
  font-size: ${(props) => props.size};
  color: ${(props) => props.color};
`;

Typography.defaultProps = {
  color: "red",
size:'20px'
};

// Usage in component
<Typography tag="h1" color="#000">Typography test color</Typography>
<Typography tag="p" color="red">Typography test color</Typography>
```

Hope this helps :)